# How can I allow a WCF Router to act as a drop-in replacement for a Web Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, wcf-routing

Let's say I currently have a (live) WCF Web Service conforming to this contract

```
namespace MyWeb
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyWebService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "VersionCheck/")]
        bool VersionCheck(string version, string device);
    }
}
```

This currently works as expected; A web client uses AJAX to POST the arguments (as a JSON string) to the service, and then the web service returns a JSON response.

However, I need to break API compatibility for upcoming client versions, and I can't guarantee that all users will be using the updated version of the client right away.

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Rename `MyWebService` to something indicating the version of the
   client it was intended for, such as `MyWebService_1_0`.
2. Create a new routing service, in the same vein as [IRequestReplyRouter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.routing.irequestreplyrouter.aspx), and name it
   `MyWebService` to serve as a drop-in replacement for the existing service
3. Include a `version` header in the request's HTTP headers so that the new `MyWebService`
   can determine the appropriate real service (in this case, `MyWebService_1_0`) to route
   to.

Theoretically, this seems straightforward. The problem I am running into is that, whenever I try to create the above service, Ajax calls to `www.mywebsite.com/MyWebService.svc/VersionCheck/` just fail completely (and remember, in this situation, `MyWebService` is a routing service, not the same service we started out with).

I guess my question is, what can I do to allow for a router to work as a drop-in replacement in this situation? Or, is there a better way to handle this? Client-side updates are not a possibility at this time.

Comment: Can't you simply call the new implementation from the current one rather then using routing service ? any specific reason ?

Comment: can you post your router configuration?

Comment: what does "fail completely" mean in your situation? provide an error stack